# Designing WPF application based on PSD

Tags: wpf, colors, gradient, psd

What is the best approach to design WPF application based on design template in PSD format?

Are there some special programs to use or is the best way to take a part by part from the original PSD format and design it manually ?

My biggest concern is how to hit the original gradient brushes and colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression Blend can convert photoshop files to XAML.

See: http://expressioniq.com/?p=965

However, this is a licensed product.

Comment: Yes I agree. Expression Bland can help but I am not sure if it can be trusted completelly. Maybe is better to divide the original into pieces and build the WPF xaml manually in order to achieve as faithful a copy of the original.

Comment: I will try the expression products.